# End of abilities given off by creatures

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I'm attacking with creatures that give off abilities and the other person blocks and kills the creature does its ability die off with the creature at that same moment leaving the others creatures without it.

Comment: No, because as long as those other creatures attacked in the same turn the given abilities don't go away until your turn is over even if the creature that gives off the ability dies. (Dragonlord 619/ iron giant)

Comment: huh? Is this a magic the gathering question, or a Warhammer 40k question. What do you mean by "give off abilities"? The answer would change if the ability is a static ability (creatures you control get +1/+1), or a triggered ability (whenever a creature you control is blocked).

Answer (score 2):

"Give off abilities" is not clear. It helps if you use proper jargon or at least an example. I believe you are talking about continuous effects created by static abilities such as [Wizened Cenn](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Wizened%20Cenn)'s.

Effects created by static abilities take effect the moment the object on which they reside enters the battlefield, and they end the moment that object leaves the battlefield.

For example, say you have [Wizened Cenn](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Wizened%20Cenn) and [Amrou Seekers](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Amrou%20Seekers) on the battlefield, and your opponent deals 2 damage to each of your creature. This marks two damage on both your creatures. This kills off your Cenn, which reverts your Seekers to 2/2, which kills them off too.

Comment: Since he mentioned attacking with these creatures, I assume that he's wondering about combat damage, specifically how much damage is creatures will deal. Might want to mention that since all combat damage is simultaneous, he will deal the increased amount.